# Log4j configuration: How to create a new folder for each day?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

So, we are using Log4j's `DailyRollingFileAppender` to create our log files.  This is really nice as it can create a new file for each day or hour.  We'd like the appender to create a new folder based on the day, then new log files based on the hour.  Is this possible?

Here is our current configuration... currently set up to dump ALL log files (created hourly) into `someFolder`.  I'd guess we can do something fancy in the "File" param to do what we want:

```
    <appender name="PlainFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="someFolder/someFileName_plain.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd-HH" />
            <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d %-5p [%t] %c{1}: %m%n" />
        </layout> 
            <filter class="com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.logging.ClassFilter">
                <param name="classNameFilter" value="com.trgr.cobalt.infrastructure.logging.LogRecord" />
                <param name="acceptOnMatch" value="false" /> 
                <param name="neutrality" value="true" />
            </filter>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with that appender, since it always appends the date to the specified filename  (so you cannot specify some special filename to achieve your result) and does not create missing directories, even if you specify some fancy date pattern.

So you may write an appender on your own or find such a custom log4j appender somewhere. Log4j's successor, logback, [has such an appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy).